# What does an echo followed immediately by a slash do in a Windows CMD file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

When examining this Windows batch/CMD file ([RefreshEnv.cmd](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/blob/master/src/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd) from Chocolatey source), I came across the following line of code:

```
echo/@echo off >"%TEMP%\_env.cmd"
```

The above creates file *_env.cmd* with content "@echo off".

What does the slash do in "echo/"?  If I leave out the slash, the resulting file is exactly same.

I am on Windows 7.

Comment: It is just a character as any else. You might see `echo.`, `echo(` and others as well. Afaik... More can be read [here](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) under "ECHO a variable" and "ECHO a new line".

Comment: Well IMO it is a convenience to use a different char from a space as a space followed by an eventually empty %var% causes an `echo is on` reply. I remember some people made comparisons which other chars are possible and have an excution speed difference.

Comment: @LotPings What is %var% in this context? Thanks.

Comment: Just the explanation why some people don't use the space as the command seperator with the echo.

Comment: @LotPings OK thanks, understand you now.

Comment: `echo` + _space_ does not allow to return an empty line, you'll receive `ECHO is on|off.` then; `echo.` is a commonly used syntax to avoid that, but this could fail if there is a file called `echo.`; `echo/` avoids that (`/` cannot occur in file names); `echo/` however fails to output a single `?` character (remember the `/?` option); so finally, `echo(` is the only secure way to echo any string... Search [DosTips](http://dostips.com) for an article about safe `echo`...

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you; I read your comment couple of times and finally understand it what's happening.  Could you please post it as an answer? Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, for your command line, there is absolutely no difference whether you are writing `echo/@echo off` or `echo @echo off`, there is just the text `@echo off` echoed.

A `/` character immediately following the `echo` command is sometimes used to echo an empty line, since `echo` without any argument returns a message like `ECHO is on|off.`. A very common way to do that is to write `echo.`, although this could fail in case there is a file called `echo.` (no file name extension) in the current working directory, which would then be executed unintentionally.

---

In general, there are the following characters in `cmd` which separate tokens on the command line, like the command and its arguments: <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=`, the vertical tabulator <kbd>VTAB</kbd> (code `0x0B`), the form-feed <kbd>FF</kbd> (code `0x0C`) and the non-break space <kbd>NBSP</kbd> (code `0xFF`). The most commonly used token separator (which I strongly recommend) is a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. Multiple adjacent separators are treated as a single one.

There are some more characters which seem to separate a command from its arguments: `.`, `:`, `/`, `\`, `[`,`]`, `+` and `(`, although these characters seem to become part of the first argument then. (Try `type+file.txt` to type the content of `+file.txt` but not of `file.txt`.)

---

`echo` however seems to behave differently though, because not all token separators are handled equally, and the aforementioned additional characters that separate the command from its arguments are not treated as part of the arguments. This is how `echo` behaves:

- `echo` followed by nothing, or followed by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, a <kbd>TAB</kbd>, a <kbd>VTAB</kbd>, a <kbd>FF</kbd> or a <kbd>NBSP</kbd>, or a string composed by multiple such characters returns `ECHO is on|off.`;
- `echo` followed by a `,`, a `;` or an `=` returns an empty line;
- `echo` followed by a `,`, a `;` or an `=`, followed by one or more token separators returns these token separators;
- `echo` followed by a token separator, followed by a string containing at least one character other than <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>VTAB</kbd>, <kbd>FF</kbd> and <kbd>NBSP</kbd> returns that string;
- `echo` followed by `.`, `:`, `/`, `\`, `[`,`]`, `+` or `(` returns an empty line;
- `echo` followed by `.`, `:`, `/`, `\`, `[`,`]`, `+` or `(`, followed by anything else, even token separators only, returns the said anything;
- `echo` followed by `.`, `[`, `]` or `+` fails if there is a file named `echo.`, `echo[`, `echo]` and `echo+`, respectively;
- `echo` followed by `\` or `:` could also fail due to similar (but more complicated) path conflicts;
- `echo` followed `/` cannot fail due to path conflicts, but it fails if the following text begins with `?`, because `/?` is noticed, so the help text is displayed in the console rather than the given text;
- `echo` followed by `(`, followed by an arbitrary text safely returns the said arbitrary text;

So the only safe way to echo any arbitrary text is to use `echo(`. For returning an empty line I prefer to use `echo/`, because it does not look that odd as `echo(`.

There is a great thread on [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774) about how to securely return an empty line by the `echo` command and how to use the `echo` command safely.

Regard that characters like `^`, `&`, `%`, `!`, `)`, `<`, `>` and `|` need to be escaped properly to be returned correctly by `echo`; this is however necessary because of the command interpreter `cmd` and has nothing to do with the `echo` command.

Comment: Are there any token separators other than semicolon? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, SPACE, TAB, `,`, `;`, `=` and the non-break space (`0xFF`) are token separators for `cmd`...