# Difference between Echo[Special Character]

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

When writing batch files,
I found out some people uses `Echo.`,`Echo/`,`Echo(` etc...These echo a blank line, so what is the difference between these `Echo[Special Character]`?

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1900

Comment: Or read forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) also on dostips.com.

Comment: Related: [What does an echo followed immediately by a slash do in a Windows CMD file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41514776)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use many different characters with `echo`.
One of `.[]+\:/,;=(`.

But there are multiple requirements for a *good* choice.

1. It should create an empty line (not `ECHO iS OFF`)

   2. It should be able to output any content if used with a (delayed) variable
   3. It shouldn't fail when a special namend file exists in the current directory

The first point works for all characters (from the list).
The second point fails for `\:.` with content like `\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe
echo.!var!
```

`,;=` fails with `/?` and `/` fails with `?`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=/?
echo=!var!
```

The third point fails for `.[]+`

```
echo echo HELLO FROM %~f0 > echo[.bat
echo[ This fails
```

**The only one that works always is `echo(`**

Comment: Does `echo/` really fail with `/?`? I think it only fails with `?`... +1 anyway!

Comment: `echo( `  always give me this error:  `echo( is not an internal............... ` ( testing on Win7 64 bits)

Comment: @SteveFest That's very curious, `echo(` runs on many systems and I never heard, that it fails. It works directly on the command line as also in a batch file

Comment: @SteveFest Are you sure, that your batch file is ANSI encoded? Does any other command work in the file?

Comment: @SteveFest, `echo(` does work, unless you are using it immediately after a `:Label` within a parenthesised block of code, which is in fact caused by the label handling...