# Question mark get url encoded in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, url, escaping

I'm having trouble with a batch script that worked a few days ago, but now doesnt work, even though no changes has been made!
I believe something has changed in the system without my knowledge.

The expected link is:

```
order.htm?order=12345
```

But it becomes like this: (notice the question mark becomes %3F)

```
order.htm%3Forder=12345
```

The code is as follows:

```
@echo off
echo.

set "drive=%~d0"
set "runningDir=%~dp0"

:start
ClS
Echo.
Set /P Job=Enter number:^>

@echo off

if exist c:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe goto program_files_x86

:program_files_x86
start c:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-print-preview --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --allow-file-access-from-files %runningDir%\order.htm?order=%job%
goto end

:end
goto start
```

Any suggestions?

Best Regards
Niclas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes should be usually used around entire folder/file string and not just parts of it.

Command **START** interprets first double quoted string as title for the new command process. Therefore on starting a GUI application an empty title string specified with `""` should be used on **START** command line to avoid interpreting the double quoted file name with path of the application to execute as title string.

The batch file path referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with a backslash. Therefore don't specify an extra backspace after this string or an environment variable like `runningDir` with path of batch file. By the way: The current directory on running a batch file can be different to directory of batch file. For that reason the name `runningDir` is not good as misleading. A better name for the environment variable is `BatchPath`.

It is possible to use `start` as label in a batch file. But it is not advisable to do that because of command **START** which makes it difficult to search for label respectively search for command. It is better to use a label like `Begin`.

In an url the directory separator is `/` and therefore each backslash (directory separator on Windows) in batch file path should be substituted by a slash.

The url should start with the protocol like `http://` (Hypertext Transfer Protocol) and should be enclosed completely in double quotes.

And last `echo/` or `echo(` is better than `echo.` for printing a blank line, see [Difference between Echo[Special Character]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647005/) for details.

The rewritten batch code:

```
@echo off
echo/

set "BatchPath=%~dp0"
set "BatchPath=%BatchPath:\=/%"

:Begin
clS
echo/
set /P "Job=Enter number: "

if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" goto program_files_x86

:program_files_x86
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-print-preview --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --allow-file-access-from-files "http://%BatchPath%order.htm?order=%Job%"
goto end

:end
goto Begin
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `start /?`